# selenium/standalone-chrome using in k8s

Tags: selenium, kubernetes, selenium-chromedriver

I try to use selenium/standalone-chrome in k8s - when the pod is port forwarded everything is perfect anytimes. I use it with side runner:

```
selenium-side-runner  --server http://localhost:4444/wd/hub .....
```

But when I try to reach it over ingress ( `selenium-side-runner  --server http://ingressdomain/wd/hub`   ) i get

> NoSuchSessionError: This driver instance does not have a valid session
> ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.

message. Everything is tha same. The http://ingressdomain/wd/hub   is reachable from browser. Logs (INFO) are the same in the standalone-chrome pod.

Comment: I assume that you use `ingressdomain:4444` only?

Comment: No, ingress is listening on 443 and 80 port ( ingress (80,443)-->svc(5555)-->pod(4444) )

Comment: Exec inside the pod and see if you are able to resolve the ingressdomain